# Is there a way to configure Docker's embedded DNS server's upstream nameserver's port?

Tags: linux, docker, dns

### General context

Docker daemon comes with an embedded DNS server. It resolves local Docker swarm and network records and forwards queries for external records to an upstream nameserver configured with --dns [1](http://docs.docker.oeynet.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/).

Docs say you can set an IP address for this upstream nameserver with `--dns=[IP_ADDRESS...]`. The default port used is 53.

### My question

Can I configure the port used as well?

My host's `/etc/docker/daemon.json` shows `"dns": ["10.99.0.1"],`. Is  there a way for me to specify something like `"dns": ["10.99.0.1:53"]`, so that dockerd always knows to forward DNS queries to port 53?

### My use case

In my case, 10.99.0.1 is the IP of a localhost bridge interface. I run a local DNS caching server on this host. So DNS queries sent to 10.99.0.1:53 work. But dockerd forwards queries originating from containers connected to user-defined bridge networks (created with `docker network create`) to non-standard ports it picks. See terminal output below.

### Detailed terminal output and debugging info

*"toogle" is a Docker container connected to a Docker network I created with `docker network create`. 127.0.0.11 is another loopback address. DNS queries originating from within Docker containers connected to user-defined Docker networks are destined for this IP.*

Is Docker's embedded DNS server actually running?

DNS queries are routed by toogle's firewall rules this way.

```
$ sudo nsenter -n -t $(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} toogle) iptables -t nat -nvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 60 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 60 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DOCKER_OUTPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.11

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DOCKER_POSTROUTING  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.11

Chain DOCKER_OUTPUT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.11           tcp dpt:53 to:127.0.0.11:37619   <-- look at this rule
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.11           udp dpt:53 to:127.0.0.11:58552   <-- look at this rule

Chain DOCKER_POSTROUTING (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 SNAT       tcp  --  *      *       127.0.0.11           0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:37619 to::53
    0     0 SNAT       udp  --  *      *       127.0.0.11           0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:58552 to::53
```

Whatever's listening on those ports is accepting TCP and UDP connections

```
$ sudo nsenter -n -t $(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} toogle) nc 127.0.0.11 37619 -vz

127.0.0.11: inverse host lookup failed: Host name lookup failure
(UNKNOWN) [127.0.0.11] 37619 (?) open

$ sudo nsenter -n -t $(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} toogle) nc 127.0.0.11 58552 -vzu

127.0.0.11: inverse host lookup failed: Host name lookup failure
(UNKNOWN) [127.0.0.11] 58552 (?) open
```

But there's no DNS reply from either

```
$ sudo nsenter -n -t $(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} toogle) dig @127.0.0.11 -p 58552 accounts.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.14-Ubuntu <<>> @127.0.0.11 -p 58552 accounts.google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached


$ sudo nsenter -n -t $(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} toogle) dig @127.0.0.11 -p 37619 accounts.google.com +tcp

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.14-Ubuntu <<>> @127.0.0.11 -p 37619 accounts.google.com +tcp
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

dockerd is listening for DNS queries at that IP and port from within toogle.

```
$ sudo nsenter -n -p -t $(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} toogle) ss -utnlp
Netid        State          Recv-Q         Send-Q                    Local Address:Port                    Peer Address:Port
udp          UNCONN         0              0                            127.0.0.11:58552                        0.0.0.0:*             users:(("dockerd",pid=10984,fd=38))
tcp          LISTEN         0              128                          127.0.0.11:37619                        0.0.0.0:*             users:(("dockerd",pid=10984,fd=40))
tcp          LISTEN         0              128                                   *:80                                 *:*             users:(("toogle",pid=12150,fd=3))
```

But dockerd is trying to forward the DNS query to 10.99.0.1, which is my docker0 bridge network interface.

```
$ sudo journalctl --follow -u docker
-- Logs begin at Tue 2019-11-05 18:17:27 UTC. --
Apr 22 15:43:12 my-host dockerd[10984]: time="2021-04-22T15:43:12.496979903Z" level=debug msg="[resolver] read from DNS server failed, read udp 172.20.0.127:37928->10.99.0.1:53: i/o timeout"
Apr 22 15:43:13 my-host dockerd[10984]: time="2021-04-22T15:43:13.496539033Z" level=debug msg="Name To resolve: accounts.google.com."
Apr 22 15:43:13 my-host dockerd[10984]: time="2021-04-22T15:43:13.496958664Z" level=debug msg="[resolver] query accounts.google.com. (A) from 172.20.0.127:51642, forwarding to udp:10.99.0.1"
```

dockerd forwards the DNS query that asks for nameserver 127.0.0.11:58552 to 10.99.0.1 but only changes the IP and not the port. So the DNS query is forwarded to 10.99.0.1:58552 and nothing is listening at that port.

```
$ dig @10.99.0.1 -p 58552 accounts.google.com
[NO RESPONSE]

$ nc 10.99.0.1 58552  -vz
10.99.0.1: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host
(UNKNOWN) [10.99.0.1] 58552 (?) : Connection refused
```

A DNS query to 10.99.0.1:53 works as expected.

```
dig @10.99.0.1 -p 53 accounts.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.14-Ubuntu <<>> @10.99.0.1 -p 53 accounts.google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 53674
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;accounts.google.com.       IN  A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
accounts.google.com.    235 IN  A   142.250.1.84
;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.99.0.1#53(10.99.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 22 17:20:09 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this. I also misread the output. Docker daemon was forwarding to port 53.

`read udp 172.20.0.127:37928->10.99.0.1:53: i/o timeout`